# Difference between two string time and now

Tags: c#, .net, time

I have a string like that 03223311 (hhmmssff). I'm going to compare it with DateTime.Now and see if the difference between these to values is lower than 200 miliseconds.

```
   xdate="03223311";

   if(Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(xdate) - Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssff")))<200)
```

I tried to run the line above in a timer with interval of 1 but I can not reach to that condition even if I change xdate to current time... . Do you know how to solve the problem or even a better approach?

Comment: And we still doesn't have an answer why this is not work. Only I know that DateTime.Now is useless when you make a performance measurments. It's not updated at milliseconds. In such cases i have to use stopwatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = "03223311";

var diff = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(
                TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, "hhmmssff", null)
           ).TotalMinutes; //or any other value like TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first convert the string into a DateTime so that you can compare apples to apples and utilized the features of the DateTime object. Once you have two DateTime objects, you can subtract them to get a TimeSpan. TimeSpan will have a TotalMilliseconds property that you can compare to your 200 constant.

```
var xdateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(xdate, "hhmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var difference = DateTime.Now - xdateValue;
if (difference.TotalMilliseconds < 200) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (((DatetTime.Now - DateTime.ParseExact("03223311 ", "hhmmssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Milliseconds > 200)
{

}
```